# Как написать путь к картинке в css

Tags: html, css

Начинающий программист , уже который раз , пытаясь поставить картинку на background утыкаюсь мордой в путь до нее, не понимаю как его построить, если в ссылках брузера и пути к файлу на пк всё понятно, файл один за другим через "/" , то здесь я не понимаю от чего отталкиваться.  Объясните как построить путь , чтобы картинка отображалась.(underwater.png) Скриншоты с расположением файлов ниже:[image: Папка со всеми файлами] [image: Папка с файлом css] [image: папка с изображениями].

Comment: Во-первых, это к программированию не имеет никакого отношения. Во-вторых, `background-image: url(../img/underwater.png)` не работает или в чём проблема? Где конкретно вам вообще нужно прописать этот путь?

Comment: Кирилица и пробелы в пути. Жесть

Comment: При импорте CSS, в site-test.html, директория не `./CSS/www/css/` а `./CSS/www/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите относительный путь, иными словами "путь относительно расположения css файла"
у вас следующая структура проекта
www - корень проекта.
css1 и img - дочерние каталоги.
Картинка находится в папке img.
Т.к. css файл находится в папке css1

1. Начинаем перемещение относительно расположения style.css, полный путь к которому "/www/css1/style.css", иными словами, мы сейчас находимся в "/www/css1/"
2. "../" Переходим из каталога css1 в родительский каталог - www;
3. "../img/" Из родительского каталога переходим в каталог img;
4. "../img/underwater.png" Указываем нужный файл.

"../img/underwater.png" - Результат.

Почитайте подробней про относительные и абсолютные пути, и про то, как используются ключи путей "/", "..", "./", и у вас все встанет на свои места.

Answer (score 0):

Просто перенесите файл со стилями в папку www и указывайте путь так:

```css
background-image: url(img/underwater.png);
```