# Не ставиться фон background-image

Tags: html, css

Я уже и путь проверял и чёрточки двойные ставил и фотку менял и размер ставил ,не работает,в саблайме body светится красным ,что не является хорошо

```css
body {
    background-image: url(C:\Users\38066\Desktop\Веб\Лаб2\spac.jpg);
    width: 1920px; /* ширина */
    height: 50px; /* высота */
}
  TABLE {
    width:100%; /* Ширина таблицы */
   }
   TD {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  .semi {
    opacity: 0.7;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Space</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1><big><strong><center>Космос</big></strong></h1>
<pre><center>TEXT</u></p>
   <p>(c)Карл Саган</p>
   </center>
<center><table>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#8A2BE2"><p><pre>  TEXT.</pre></p></td>
<td style="background-color:#8A2BE2"><p><img src="C:\Users\38066\Desktop\Веб\Лаб2\Space.jpg" alt="Space" width="600";height="450";></p>
   <b><center>Boeing Starliner</center></b></td></td>
<td style="background-color:#8A2BE2"><pre> TEXT</pre></td>
</tr>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="2">
    <p>TEXT:</b> <i>CH<sub>3</sub>-NO<sub>2</sub></i></p>
<tr bgcolor="#BA55D3">
<th> <center>TEXT</center></th>
</tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#BA55D3" >SpaceX</td><td bgcolor="#BA55D3" >Америка</td><td bgcolor= #BA55D3>1 </td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#BA55D3" >NASA</td><td bgcolor="#BA55D3" >Америка</td><td bgcolor= #BA55D3>2</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#BA55D3" >Planet Labs</td><td bgcolor="#BA55D3" >Америка</td><td bgcolor=#BA55D3>3</td></tr>
</table>
 <p>TEXT.</p>
  <progress max="100" value="35">
    Загружено на <span id="value">35</span>%
  </progress>
 <p>TEXT.</p>
  <form>
  <p><b>TEXT:</b></p>
<p><textarea name="comment"> </textarea></p>
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="SpaceX">
   <input type="hidden" name="password" value="NASA"></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Відправити"></p>
   <p><time>2021-03-03</time></p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Слеши переворачивали?

Comment: у вас почему-то селекторы для таблицы и ячейки в верхнем регистре

Comment: у Вас путь к картинке как-то трешёво прописан

Comment: Слешы вертел уже как угодно,

Comment: Я использовал путь из свойст фото,поэтому там впорядке

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1071407/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-css

Comment: URL в кавычки брать надо